# Consider a cube whose faces are given and a triangle whose vertices given then the number of point of intersection of cube and triangle is

Tags: 3d, coordinate-systems, plane-geometry

Consider a cube whose faces are given by

$x+y+z=3\sqrt{3}$,

$x+y+z=2\sqrt{3}$,

$4x-5y+z=\sqrt{42}$,

$4x-5y+z=2\sqrt{42}$,

$2x+y-3z=\sqrt{14}$,

$2x+y-3z=2\sqrt{14}$,

and a triangle whose vertices are $(2, 1, 3)$, $(1, 1, 1)$, $(3, 1, 0)$,
then find the number of point of intersection of cube and triangle.

My work

I checked position of each point w.r.t 6 planes, then found that first point is outside the cube, second point is on one of the face and third point is inside the cube. Thus there should be 2 intersection, 
Is there some other way of solving ?

Comment: Please use mathjax to properly write the equations of the planes. An intersection is an intersection of sets. Which is the set associated to the cube? (Only the vertices, the six squares, the full compact box delimited by the cube?) Which is the set associated to the triangle?

Comment: I checked your solution and obtained one vertex of the triangle inside the cube, the other two outside. Before concluding that the sides of the triangle have two point in common with the faces of the cube, one must check whether the line connecting the external points intersects the cube.